# Setting browser print settings using JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, next.js, printing

Is it possible to change browser settings when you print a page

```
window.print()
```

to overwrite the settings? - margins, paper size, etc.?

I have some print styles, so the printed page looks decent, but if the browser does not have margins on default and paper size on A4, it can break. Can I force this setting?

Comment: This is not possible. Print settings are controlled by the browser outside the control of JS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.